# Assign an xml output into xml for BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have an output of string, that is not an xml document, but is not saved anywhere.  When part of my script runs, it displays that xml output into a variable called r.text

How can i assign that to be xml?

print r.text will print

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE SIMPLE_RETURN SYSTEM "https://qualysapi.qg2.apps.qualys.com/api/2.0/simple_return.dtd">

<DATA>

  <RESPONSE>

    <DATETIME>2017-06-16T15:26:14Z</DATETIME>

    <TEXT>Report launched successfully.</TEXT>

    <ITEM_LIST>

      <ITEM>

        <KEY>ID</KEY>

        <VALUE>2359805</VALUE>

      </ITEM>

    </ITEM_LIST>

  </DATA>

</SIMPLE_RETURN>
```

this is what i tried but it does not work and i get an error
Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

```
req = r.text
xml = BeautifulSoup(req, 'xml')
for item in xml.findAll('VALUE'):
    print item.text
return value
```

i'm trying to assign item to the text value's inside of VALUE, so 2359805 assign to the item variable

Comment: I just tried `BeautifulSoup(req)` and it worked fine, but gave me the warning: `UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.` You can either use BeautifulSoup without a second argument or you can use 'lxml' instead of 'xml'.

Comment: when i get rid of the sec argument i get thisNo parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 78 of the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_launcher.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

Comment: BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html.parser")

  markup_type=markup_type))

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you use the code that the warning suggests? Did it work without the second argument? (You could just ignore the warning.) I guess there is a way to install a different parser, but I would rather use what is already installed.

Comment: its not html, its xml

Comment: Unless this code is part of a big and important project, I would still suggest you use "html.parser" if it works with your data. Otherwise you could do as described [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) to get a xml-parser.